# What is the best tool for simulating Vacuum and Fluids together?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, simulations, vacuum, software

I require a software to simulate Fluid simulation with the capability of supporting vacuum simulation. My requirements are that all numbers must reflect their real counterparts almost exactly. For example I need to mix Fluid, Air and Vacuum.

I have tried RealFlow but it doesn't support Vacuum.

Any body knows any software for this?

Comment: This seems to run afoul of the [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) a couple of possible ways. If you are asking how to write such software then the restriction on computational physics applies. If you are asking for existing software, then the restriction on make-a-list questions comes into play. If you can provide some clarity here we can try to help you get this moved/re-writen.

Comment: I know the simulation is not an if else programming specifically the Fluid Simulation. I'm looking for software names, I'm tried lots of them with no luck. I need to know which available softwares can do this.

Comment: Many, but not all, Stack Exchange site discourage questions for which the answer would form a list (especially if the list might be open ended). Physics is one of these, which makes this questions a bit of a problem here. However, I see that the [scientific computation beta site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) has a more nuanced attitude. I'm going to ask the moderators over there if they would like this question because I think it would fit better if they do.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what you have already tried and what methods you are using? [vmd](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/) might be able to help, but it is hard to know from the description you have given.

Comment: "Vacuum" is just low density gas. So it's hard to know what you mean when you need to include vacuum as a separate element in a fluids solver, if said solver can already handle gas dynamics.

Comment: He's talking about cavitation.

Comment: Or really loud sounds? Gasses (e.g. air) and Liquids are both Fluids - you mean Liquid, Gas and Vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

USim can do vacuum + gas http://www.txcorp.com/home/usim/usim-overview.  Not technically true vacuum, but 9 orders of magnitude density jumps.  It doesn't support an incompressible fluid (liquid) though.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for doesn't entirely make sense.

Vacuum ins't anything, *per se*.  Vacuum is the absence of things, e.g. particles, pressure, etc.  A perfect vacuum doesn't exist, thus generally one is interested in varying degrees of low-density fluids.  Thus one would most likely rephrase that you're looking for a simulation of two fluids, with **strongly** varying density.

The standard method of simulating fluids is with either a grid based hydrodynamics code (a so-called 'Eulerian' code), or a smoothed particle hydrodynamics (SPH, a `Lagrangian' code).  Grid codes have trouble simulating large differences in density (especially over small spatial scales), which suggests that you should try using an SPH code.  In astrophysics, which is the field I am most familiar with, the standard SPH code is called [Gadget](http://www.mpa-garching.mpg.de/gadget/) (note that it ***can*** be used for simulations of small scale objects, instead of galaxies and larger---which it is generally advertised for).

If that is insufficient, you should google it, or be more specific.

Comment: Thanks @zhermes for your answer. I have a tube filled with water. Consider the case that when the water goes out of one side of tube on the other side because of low pressure (or at the maximum, vaccum) the water should be sucked in, by vacuum I mean this. Better to say I want sucking feature

Comment: @MohsenAfshin, suction isn't a new/different feature that needs to be added or explicitly included.  Its a build in component of fluid dynamics.  The only issue is how to implement that in a simulation --- most likely you would use some sort of 'boundary condition' on the side where the water is leaving.